# example object path of custom registry

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

The CloudFormation registry lists the resources, both private and public (AWS), that are available for use in your CloudFormation account.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/registry.html

The documentation has mentioned this command...

```
aws cloudformation register-type --type-name My::Resource::Example --schema-handler-package [s3 object path] --type RESOURCE
```

Is there any example of [s3 object path] ?

Answer (score 0):

An `[s3 object path]` is just the combination of s3 protocol, bucket name & s3 destination Key.

To illustrate this with an example; say:

Bucket name: **my-bucket-name**

Destination key: **my-s3-destination-key.zip**

The command will look like:

```
aws cloudformation register-type --type-name My::Resource::Example --schema-handler-package s3://my-bucket-name/my-s3-destination-key.zip --type RESOURCE
```

Comment: What I mean by example? A "real" file with sample code.

Comment: [s3 object path] is a link to a zip file that contains your resources. Linking external AWS zip files as an answer will non meet StackOverflows standards.